# How to extend yAxis grid Line to full plot area in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I want to increase the chart grid lines to fill the width of the graph.

I have got it till this point: https://jsfiddle.net/mukeshshamra1201/8pu9a5c4/97/

I have used y-axis property to achieve something, but I am not able to figure out the rest.

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
        title : "",
     gridLineDashStyle: 'ShortDash',
    labels: {
    align :"left",
    x:-6,
    y:-3
    }
}
```

I want something kike this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `spacingLeft` and `spacingRight` to **0**:

```
chart: {
    ...
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3Lpsz0hd/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.spacing